# Delphi: Cannot capture Ctrl+C if user pressed the sequence too quickly

Tags: delphi

I am trying to capture when a user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in order to copy some text to the clipboard. If the user deliberately presses and holds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>... then presses <kbd>C</kbd> it will register.

```
procedure <anObject>.KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin    
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (upcase(Char(key)) = 'C')
    then
      begin
        //Copy code    
      end;
end;
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered just setting the `Shortcut` property of the menu item or action associated with that command? Then you don't have to check for each possible shortcut manually like this. You also won't have to worry about accidentally accepting Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C when you only wanted Ctrl+C.

Comment: I would but I did forget to mention that this is a DevExpress component. It doesn't afford me the same options as regular components. I will keep that in mind for other components. Thanks!

Comment: strange thing in delphi is, if alt is presssed and then control, control onKeydown doesn't fire, not yet sure why. Maybe shift state can be used to accurately get the state of the control key =D Nope still not working, this is weird. Press alt first then control, doesn't fire any handlers for control... I guess maybe alt is causing some kind of VCL activation to go to next control or something weird, or activating menu of form or something.

Comment: or (Msg.message = WM_SYSKEYDOWN) helps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ctrl+C is translated to a character message. So you better use a `OnKeyPress` handler (which is fired in response to a `WM_CHAR`):

```
procedure <anObject>.KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = ^C then
    begin
      // Copy code
    end;
end;
```

**update:**
I believe what's happening is this: when pressing quickly, the user is pressing 'Ctrl', then pressing 'C', then releasing 'Ctrl', lastly releasing 'C'. As you can see when the OnKeyUp for 'C' is fired the 'Ctrl' key is already released. You won't have this kind of problem with the translated message, if the OS registered the 'copy' key then OnKeyPress will be fired.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a sequence, it is a key combination. This means that Ctrl and C must be pressed ***at the same time***. If the user doesn't do that, it can't be captured as Ctrl+C.

But I am guessing. I can't tell what the user is doing. Perhaps there is also a problem with the keyboard or the driver for it.

---

To account for what Rob said (accidently accepting other shift keys), change your code to:

```
if (Shift = [ssCtrl]) and (Upcase(Char(Key)) = 'C') then
```

Comment: I will definitely do Shift = ... instead of how I originally did it. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 4):

Usually, OnKeyDown is more preferable then OnKeyup for such combo.  Because users usually know to press those shift key before the char key but don't have a strict sense of which one to release first.  Also, you can change the var Key to 0 to prevent the keys to be further interpreted by other levels of key events to override some default behaviour.

Comment: I hadn't considered that but you're right, OnKeyDown does seem like a better place to put this code

Answer (score 0):

```
Procedure TForm1.StringGrid1KeyPress (Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);

 Var
  Sel: TGridRect; // Selecting the Scenes
  St: String; // Stroke
  R, c: word; // Row-Stroke, Col-Column

  Begin
 If Key = ^ C then
    Begin
     St: = ''; / / A full explanation of the structure
  Sel: = StringGrid1.Selection; // Wait a while for a loose ticket
  For r: = Sel.Top to Sel.Bottom do // query the lines of the first row
  Begin
    For c: = Sel.Left to Sel.Right do // query the number of lines in the foreground
    // Scribble in the Stroke of a Distributor
    If c = Sel.Right then St: = St + StringGrid1.Cells [c, r] else St: = St + StringGrid1.Cells [c, r] + # 9;
    St: = St + # 13 # 10; // the pattern of the stencil
  End;
  ClipBoard.AsText: = St; // Displays the alarm
    End;

End;
```